# pixulated texture of character

Tags: texturing, objects, 3d-view, blender-internal-render-engine

character in my blender is Low quality 
[image: viewport]

but in the render is:
[image: render]

I want render quality = quality in 3D view

Comment: what exactly do you mean by “low quality”?

Comment: character is opaque

Comment: You want it to be transparent?

Comment: no no . See the photos carefully

Comment: I want to be clear picture

Comment: You mean without the bones?

Comment: i dont know . i download characters in https://rymdnisse.net/downloads/minecraft-blender-rig.html

Comment: The grey triangular things are bones.  They are used to move the character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the pixelated look in the view port you have to turn off *Mipmaps*.
That setting is in the user preferences under the *System* tab.

[image: mip maps setting]

---

For a small texture to be rendering like that, both *MIP Map* and *Interpolation* bust be unchecked. Those settings are in the texture tab of the properties window.

[image: texture settings]